# What is in python, fastest way of reversing a part of a list in place?

Tags: python, list, slice

Supopse I have the a huge list (say ten million elements) and I want to reverse all of the elements except last. The easiest aproach is:

```
a[0:-1] = a[-1::-1]
```

But the problem is that I think a temporary list is created. If it is so, how can avoid it?

[Edit]
For a more general case consider reversing a middle part of the list:

Comment: What do you mean by "temporary list is created"?

Comment: A temporary list is created. To avoid that, use a loop where you manually do this. Is there some reason you are trying to avoid creating an intermediate list?

Comment: @LeoArad `a[1::-1]` creates a list. Even if it didn't, as an implementation detail, I'm pretty sure that slice assignment creates a list anyway

Comment: It's referring to the same python list object after slicing a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; id(a); 1888226056264; a[0:2] = a[1::-1];  id(a); 1888226056264

Comment: @LeoArad I beleive the OP is referring to the `a[1::-1]` which does create a new list

Comment: I edited the question changing the numbers of elements to be reversed for the temorary object created have an efficiency impact

Comment: I think there should be a more efficient way than looping. In this particular case I could remove last element, call a.reverse() and then append the element back. But it wouldnt do for the general case

Comment: Why isn't looping efficient? What is your criteria here?

Comment: @LeoArad yes, no one is disputing that. An new, intermediate list is created anyway

Comment: Temporary objects are a lot cheaper than interpreter overhead. Anything you do to avoid the temporary will introduce too much interpreter overhead to be worthwhile. (Also you screwed up the slice endpoints.)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve list reversal, except last item , i would just do -

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> temp=a.pop()
>>> a.reverse()
>>> a.append(temp)
>>> print(a)
[4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
```

Comment: The question was updated, and OP is looking for a much more generalised solution instead of fixed reversing except last.

Comment: The *time* complexity will be the same for all the approaches, O(N).

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you may want to avoid copying the list is if you think it is too big for doing possible repeated copies.

I think there is no other way of doing it (without copies) than going manual:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def revert_slice(first, last, a_list):
    while first < last:
        a_list[first], a_list[last] = a_list[last], a_list[first]
        first += 1
        last -= 1

revert_slice(0, 2, a)
print(a)
```

Outputs:

```
[3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```

In the call, only a temporary copy of the reference is made, not a list copy.